# DMA settings in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, dma, pio

My Acer Aspire One 2GB has suddenly started running as slow as molasses. It can sometime take up to a minute to open a program. Googling around I see that my HD may have switched from DMA to PIO after some crashes.

I've found info on seeing if that's the case for previous Win versions, but looking in Device Manager for Windows 10, I can't seem to find any info. Where can I find out what mode it is in and how to switch it back if it has gone to PIO?

Thanks.